# from import statements in Python

Tags: python, import

I'm a little confused by the from import statements in Python.  In particular, how I can import a class from a module that is within a package.  For example, if I have a package named my package that has two modules (module 1 and module 2), how can I import a specific class from module 1 within module 2?

What I'm finding currently is that I need to (within module two) do the following...

```
from package import module1
module1.class1()
```

While this works, I'd much rather be able to access class1() directly from module 2 as it is not very readable .  However, the following syntax doesn't work...

```
from package import module1.class1
```

Also, it won't let me simply go...

```
from module1 import class1
```

How does one import a class which is in a module within a package, directly within a separate module within that package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```
from package.module1 import class1
```

If as you say you're importing from within the same package, you can also do

```
from .module1 import class1
```

The `.` means "the  position in the package hierarchy of the module doing the importing".  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) for info.